# Limit search by channel on the form rather than the results template

Tags: search

I'd like to use the same results template for all of my search functions so I'm wondering if it's possible to limit the search to a specific channel i.e. news or calendar in the form rather than in the results template.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd do it just like querying for any other element in Craft.  i.e.

```
{% set results = craft.entries({
    search: query,
    section: 'news'
}) %}
```

Comment: Thanks. So where would I add this?  Within the <form> tag?

Comment: Like so: https://craftcms.com/docs/templating/search-form

Comment: Thanks. Yes, I’ve seen that vMy question was can I limit the channel in the form rather than the results template or will I need two separate results templates, one for news and one for all?

Thanks.

Comment: Just wondered if this was possible or not. If not I'll just go ahead and create separate results templates. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Totally possible. Easy way to do it, is to add a hidden input field to the form for whatever section you want to search – the input field can be named anything, e.g. `s`:

```
<form action="{{ url('search/results') }}">
    <input type="search" name="q" placeholder="Search">
    <input type="hidden" name="s" value="vegetables"/>

    <input type="submit" value="Go">
</form>
```

The above would add an additional GET variable to the search request, named `s`. Just like with the `q` parameter, you can use [`craft.request`](https://craftcms.com/docs/templating/craft.request) to pick up that parameter's value in your search results template, and add it to the the [ElementCriteriaModel](https://craftcms.com/docs/templating/elementcriteriamodel) (i.e. `craft.entries`, in this case):

```
{% set query = craft.request.getParam('q') %}
{% set section = craft.request.getParam('s')|default('news') %}
{% set entries = craft.entries.section(section).search(query).order('score') %}
...
```

Note that it's wise to use the `|default` filter to add a default value to the `section` variable, in case the `s` GET parameter is missing or empty, for some reason – if you don't pass a section handle to the ECM, Craft searches *all* sections, which is probably not what you want.

Further: If you wanted to search multiple sections, you could do something like this:

```
<form action="{{ url('search/results') }}">
    <input type="hidden" name="s[]" value="vegetables"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="s[]" value="fruits"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="s[]" value="berries"/>
    <input type="submit" value="Go">
</form>
```

...and if you wanted to give the user control over which sections to search, you could opt for an input type other than hidden, e.g. checkboxes:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="s[]" value="vegetables"/>Vegetables
<input type="checkbox" name="s[]" value="fruits"/>Fruits
<input type="checkbox" name="s[]" value="berries"/>Berries
```

And finally, the same strategy would, of course, work fine for any other parameter/field value you can pass to an ElementCriteriaModel. You could, for instance, add a dropdown field enabling the user to filter search results by author:

```
<form action="{{ url('search/results') }}">
    <input type="search" name="q" placeholder="Search">
    <select name="a">
        <option value="">All authors</option>
        <option value="3">Julia</option>
        <option value="53">Gary</option>
        <option value="13">Susie</option>
    </select>
    <input type="submit" value="Go">
</form>
```

In this case, it'd probably make sense to default to `null`, which would give you results for all authors:

```
{% set query = craft.request.getParam('q') %}
{% set authorId = craft.request.getParam('a')|default(null) %}
{% set entries = craft.entries.authorId(author).search(query).order('score') %}
...
```

Comment: This worked great!  Thanks so much for the detailed explanation.

Comment: That's awesome, @fodney – feel free to mark the answer as accepted if it did the trick :)

Comment: one follow up question to this post.  How would you specify that a section not be searched? Sort of like: <input type="hidden" name="s[]" value="not vegetables"/> thx